# Cannot create baseline in Google Chart based on MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, google-api, google-visualization, baseline

Is there any possibilities to create the baseline in Google Chart based on the MySQL data. Right now I can only create the fix baseline; meaning key-in the baseline value in the coding instead of taking from MySQL data.

Hereby I include the coding and also the Google Chart image for your reference. The baseline is in red colour.

My coding is like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
  </script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.google.com/jsapi">
  </script>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
     google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});     
  </script>
```

```
  <div id = "container" style = "width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  </div>

   <script language = "JavaScript">
   function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['month', 'Performance Indicator (%)'],         
   <?php  
    $username=$_GET['username'];
    $query = "SELECT month , result_ind, target, username FROM performance WHERE username = $username";

    $exec = mysqli_query($db,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)){

   echo "[".$row['month'].",".$row['result_ind']."],";
   }
   ?>

   ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
           'title':'Month vs Performance Indicator for 2020',
            vAxis: {
            title: '%',
            baseline: 2.00,
            baselineColor: 'red'
            },
            hAxis: {
            title: 'Month'
           },
           'width':550,
           'height':400,
            pointSize: 5,
            trendlines: {
            0: {
            type: 'linear',
            color: 'purple',
            lineWidth: 5,
            opacity: 0.2,
            //visibleInLegend: true,
              }
            } 
        };

        // Instantiate and draw the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('container'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
     }
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  </script>
```

[image: Google chart with baseline in red]

Comment: which value from the sql do you want to use as the baseline?

Comment: I would like to take value of target as my baseline. is it possible to do it?